# How to purge historical data when clearing a run from Airflow dashboard?

Tags: python, airflow

Here is a typical request:

I built a DAG which updates daily from 2020-01-01. It runs an `INSERT` SQL query using {execution_date} as a parameter. Now I need to update the query and rerun for the past 6 months.

I found out that I have to pause Airflow process, `DELETE` historical data, `INSERT` manually and then re-activate Airflow process because Airflow catch-up does not remove historical data when I **clear** a run.

I'm wondering if it's possible to script the **clear** part so that every time I click a run, clear it from UI, Airflow runs a clear script in the background?

Comment: Actually we had recently the very same discussion that it would be greate to add it as a UI feature to run similar pattern. You can take a look at this discussion and maybe you can chime-in: https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/18428

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, I think here is a viable solution:

Instead of INSERT data in a DAG, use a DELETE query and then INSERT query.

For example, if I want to INSERT for {execution_date} - 1 (yesterday), instead of creating a DAG that just runs the INSERT query, I should first run a DELETE query that removes data of yesterday, and then INSERT the data.

By using this DELETE-INSERT method, both of my scenarios work automatically:

- If it's just a normal run (i.e. no data of yesterday has been inserted yet and this is the first run of this DAG for {execution_date}), the DELETE part does nothing and INSERT inserts the data properly.
- If it's a re-run, the DELETE part will purge the data already inserted, and INSERT will insert the data based on the updated script. No duplication is created.